# Android In App Billing and paid apps same primary account in different devices

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play

What would be the behaviour in following scenario:

Assume i have two devices A and B. Both have its primary account set to abc@gmail.com

1. In device A I purchased an application app1. Will I have to purchase it again in device B or will it be downloadable as I have already paid for it in device A?
2. In device A, I have made an In App Purchase(managed purchase). Will I have to pay again in device B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know about 2. but for 1 it is easy

the app purchase get associated with your google account. you can download it on as many devices as you want that are logged into the market with the account that purchased the app.

again, no idea about in app purchases.

Comment: In app purchases aslo get associated with the google account. I did try it in two devices.

Comment: that would depend thou right?
Glu mobile games for example, you can buy extra currency there as in app purchase. Say you have 2 devices, i don't think you get the currency on both devices do you?

Comment: this is applicable for managed purchases only. The currency in game will be a consumable purchase